# Построение гистограамы распределения цвета на изображении. Какую лучше всего цветувую модель использовать для решения этой задачи?

Tags: color, rgb

Имеются изображения в формате sRGB. Мне необходимо построить гистограмму распределения цветов на этом изображении, при этом, естественно, число столбцов гистограммы не должно быть очень велико (например, 256 столбцов, конкретный цвет будет относиться к конкретному бину гистограммы за счет вычисления его близости). Как можно разделить цветовое пространство sRGB на 256 промежутков для построения гистограммы? Или может для этой задачи лучше переводить изображение в другие цветовые пространства и строить гистограммы уже по ним?

Comment: Обычно делают 3 гистограммы отдельно - R, G и B

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А сколько бинов лучше всего взять для каждого канала?

Comment: Зависит от вашей ситуации. В общем виде, гистограмма это кривая/линия, а не столбчатая диаграмма